# Need to update a table with last_transaction_type by looking at the date in the transaction table and updating the master table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

Transaction_log

```
-trans_id(PK)
-policy_number (foreign key)
-payment type
-amount
-Date(DateTime)
```

Master_policy

```
- policy_number(PK)
- last_trans_type
- and some other data
```

I need to get the last payment type for each policy number and update it in master policy table using the date

I want to try and get the last date either by like ordering by date and limit it by 1 or I need to use max(date). But I cant figure out how to exactly do it as it might need a subquery.

mysql

```
UPDATE fn_policy_master
SET last_trans_type = 
    (Select max(date)
    FROM col_trans_log
    WHERE policy_number = Transaction_log.policy_number)
WHERE policy_number = Transaction_log.policy_number;
```

The above statement does not work. I was hoping to find a fix. I intend it to find the lastest payment type used and set the last_trans_type in the Master_policy to the last type used.

Comment: Would be helpful if you could provide dummy data for your tables and expected result for better visualization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a inner join between the two table and a subquery for the max date group by  policy_number

```
UPDATE Master_policy m
INNER JOIN Transaction_log log ON m.policy_number = log.policy_number 
INNER JOIN  (
  Select policy_number, max(date) max_date
  FROM Transaction_log
  GROUP BY policy_number
) t on t.policy_number = m.policy_number 
  AND log.date = t.max_date  
set m.last_trans_type = log.last_trans_type
```